# sprintf() to truncate and not round a float to x decimal places?

Tags: php, floating-point, printf

When calculating a golf handicap differential you are supposed to truncate the answer to 1 decimal place without rounding.  No idea why but...

I know how to do this using TRUNCATE() in mySQL

```
 SELECT TRUNCATE( 2.365, 1 );
// outputs 2.3
```

but I was wondering if sprintf() could do this?  The only way I know to work with decimal places in a float is ...

```
echo sprintf("%.1f", 2.365);
// outputs 2.4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What language is this in?  Assuming it's C or one of its derivatives, and assuming you always want exactly one decimal place, and assuming your values are always non-negative, you can do this:

```
float val = 12.3456;
val = floor(val*10.0)/10.0;
sprintf("%.1f", val);
```

Is there a better way?  Probably.  This is just what comes to mind.

Comment: In PHP `$val = 12.3456; $val = floor($val,1); $val = sprintf("%.1f",$val);`

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to use string operations: let sprintf round to an extra significant digit, trim, then convert back to a float

```
    function truncate_float(float $float, int $significantDigits = 4): float
    {
        $format = sprintf('%%.%df', $significantDigits + 1);

        return (float) substr(sprintf($format, $float), 0, -1);
    }
```